# magento : how to add parameter with soap request

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I am new to Magento I tried calling a category level using the Magento SOAP API with parent category id. I used the following code:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $proxy->login('user', 'password');
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

For the above code "Default Category" details are coming, I tried to call some other category by using the following code:

```
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level',12);
```

This is not working:

```
$arguments = array( 'parentCategory' => 12);
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.level',$arguments);
```

This is also not working:

Then I tried calling category tree using following code:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $proxy->login('user', 'password');
$result = $proxy->call($session,'catalog_category.tree');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

It shows the entire category tree so it means API is working but whenever I try to pass an argument it shows server not found error.

Can anyone please tell me how to pass arguments with the request.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call it like

```
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.level', array(null, null, 12));
```

For more information about the function check class

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api 

function level($website = null, $store = null, $categoryId = null)
```

If you want to pass particular website and store you can pass it instead of null parameter.

Comment: It is not working brother. still i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

i manage to get output using soapv2. but it is slow compare to soapv1 but it is giving the required out put. the code i use to pass parameter is given as below.

```
 <?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'user', 'apiKey' => 'password'));
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree((object)array('sessionId' => $session->result, 'parentId' => '12'));
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```